# Microsoft C++exception occurred in vs2019 when using pdal debug mode: std:: bad_ Alloc's situation

Tags: c++, pdal

[image]
On the debug x64 platform, running the code to (las_opts. add (las_opt)) will throw an exception, std:: bad_ Alloc's situation.
When I switch to release x-64 mode, it can run normally.

I don't know if my library is installed incorrectly.

I installed PDAl2.5 through Anconda, and I'm not sure if there are any debug or release versions of PDAL. Currently, it seems that I can only obtain the release version of PDAL.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Windows Debug build of PDAL, you will need to build it and all of its dependencies in Debug mode as well.

No pre-built Debug builds are available through Conda Forge.